# Failed to execute Matches on Element: not a valid selector

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Some time ago I wrote the following code to show certain items on my html page:

```
<div id="gameField">
@foreach (var item in Model.Characters)
{
    <div class="char" id="@item.Id"  onclick="ShowDropDown(event,this.id)">
        <img src="~/Content/Images/Characters/@item.ImageSource" class="character" alt="Character" />
        <img src="~/Content/Images/Cross.png" class="cross" alt="Cross" />
        <p>@item.Name</p>
    </div>
}
<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#" onclick="Flip()">Flip</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="Highlight()">Highlight</a>
    <a href="#" id="Guess" >Guess</a>
    <a href="#" class="red" onclick="Hide()">Hide</a>
</div>
```

the id is an number between 0 and 24.

with the following JavaScript code:

```
function ShowDropDown(event, clicked_id) {
        var Dropdown = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
        var x = event.clientX;
        var y = event.clientY;
        id = clicked_id;
        Dropdown.style.top = (y + 10) + 'px';
        Dropdown.style.left = (x + 10) + 'px';
        Dropdown.classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function (event) {
if (!event.target.matches(id)) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
        var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
        if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
            openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
        }
    }
}
}
```

Now everytime when I click on an item I get the following error message in the console:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'matches' on 'Element': '13' is not a valid selector.
>       at window.onclick (http://localhost:58203/Game?newgame=True&gameId=0&mode=2:131:31)
>   window.onclick @ Game?newgame=True&gameId=0&mode=2:131

where the 13 ofcourse changes when I click a different item.
The thing is, the code works, but this error message still shows up in the console, I've also tried to put a character in front of the id, but the error message still appears

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.matches(selector)` is supposed to get a CSS selector, so you should add a `#` before the ID:

```
if (!event.target.matches('#' + id)) {
```

But, the ID can't be just a number, so you would also have to append a character before the number of the ID to make it work properly.

See more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches

Comment: Thanks for your answer, after changing my javascript to your example and putting a character infront of the id the error remains:

Failed to execute 'matches' on 'Element': '#a 3' is not a valid selector.

Comment: That's because there seems to be a space in your ID, it should be `id="a@item.Id"`, and not `id="a @item.Id"`.

Comment: but razor won't let me put an 'a' right in front of @item.id

Comment: Ah, my bad. Does it allow `id="a@{item.Id}"`?

Comment: it does allow it, but the error message just changes to:

Failed to execute 'matches' on 'Element': '#a{12}' is not a valid selector.

Comment: Sorry (again), it should be parenthesis, `id="a@(item.id)"`.

Comment: Yea, that fixed the error, thanks. The only problem: Now it doesn't work anymore, but I guess that's up to me to find out haha

Answer (score 0):

I was using a numeric alone as an ID value.

I created an alphanumeric ID and then the query worked.

Apparently CSS ID selectors are not allowed to start with a numeric character.

Right now a quick search and I was not able to find a source in the MDN docs or anything but [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/ids-cannot-start-with-a-number/) can help you find out more.